# Django -- pass "next" parameter to cancel button?

Tags: django, redirect

I know how to pass a `next` get parameter to a view so that when the view redirects, it goes to whatever url is in `next`. Is it possible to do this with the cancel button of a form?

If my form buttons are like this:

```
  <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"><input type="button" value="Cancel Changes" onclick="window.location.href='/systems/'">
```

Is there some way to add the `next` parameter into the href instead of `/systems/`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is just HTML in your template, so why can't you do

```
onclick="window.location.href='{{ myurl }}'">
```

?

**Edit after comment**

Sounds like you need a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), which automatically adds the value of the `next` GET parameter to the context. As simple as:

```
def get_next(request):
    if 'next' in request.GET:
        return {'next': request.GET['next']}
```

Now add this to the list of `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py, and make sure you use a `RequestContext` when rendering your template (or just the new `render()` shortcut).

Comment: But that means assigning `{{ myurl }}` in every view and passing it to the template. Plus, I'm not sure what `{{ myurl }}` is going to be as it is dependant on from where a user comes from that determines the value of `{{ myurl }}`. Currently I have my `links` send a `next` parameter to each view. I need to access _that_ parameter in the template, not in the view. That's what I'm getting at.